# How does this nodejs project reference a shared library folder?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking at this project and they have multiple node projects like:

```
api
project2
project3

shared
```

So the various projects reference the shared folder like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const logging = require('shared/middlewares/logging');
  middlewares.use(logging);
}
```

https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/blob/alpha/api/routes/middlewares/index.js#L6

And the logging.js file is in the shared folder:

```
// @flow
// Log requests with debug
const debug = require('debug')('shared:middlewares:logging');

module.exports = (
  req: express$Request,
  res: express$Response,
  next: express$NextFunction
) => {
  debug(`requesting ${req.url}`);
  next();
```

So I tried to do something similiar in my node/express project but I am getting this error:

This dependency was not found:

```
* shared/middlewares/logging in ./src/middlewares/index.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save shared/middlewares/logging
```

Is there something they did in their project to allow this to work?

Comment: Do you have `shared/middlewares` directory with `logging.js` file in your project root directory?

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov Yes I do.

Comment: Actually you have to show relative path like `require('/path/to/shared/middlewares/logging')`, in particular smth like `require('./shared/middlewares/logging')`. If you don't use relative path it tries to search among installed packages, that's why it suggests you to install it because it's not found. In spectrum project it's probably somehow configured to look into root directory for packages as well, maybe webpack config somewhere, need to check.

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov they use backpad, the override is here maybe in here?  I don't see it!  https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/blob/alpha/backpack.config.js

Comment: They used NODE_PATH env variable, please check my answer below, it should help you to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally you have to show relative path for "require()" if you use your own modules, e.g.

```
require('./path/to/custom/module/file')

// In this case smth like
require('../../../shared/middlewares/logging')
```

If you do not use relative path, it will search for installed package, and that's why you got an error with suggestion to install because it's not found.

There are several ways to tell node to search package in custom directory. You can check [this link](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) for examples. In "spectrum" project it's configured by setting up **NODE_PATH** environment variable, you can see it [here](https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/blob/alpha/package.json#L209) and [here](https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/blob/alpha/package.json#L223)

At those lines you can see `NODE_PATH=./`, which tells node to look for packages in the root directory.

That's it, hope now it's clear :)